# PHP's strtotime() causes 5th dayname of month to return the following month

Tags: php, strtotime

I'd like strtotime() to only return the 5th dayname of a month if that month has the date.

For instance:

```
echo date('M d Y', strtotime('Fifth Wednesday of September 2016'));
echo date('M d Y', strtotime('Fifth Wednesday of November 2016'));
```

Returns:

```
Oct 05 2016
Nov 30 2016
```

When I'd like it to return

```
null
Nov 30 2016
```

What's the most efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Efficient way? Eliminate your first line of code. If not you have to do a comparison to make sure the returned date is in the month you're asking about and returning a null if it isn't.

Comment: Ha - not quite what I'm looking for ;).  Does strtotime() have any logic built in to account for this or am I left to check the result's month against the starting month?

Comment: Well to answer your last comment. [RT?M on `strtotime()` its available to all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: Wasn't sure if there was an alternate route I wasn't thinking through.  Going to go ahead and assume comparing the months after setting the new date value with strtotime() is the best route here.

Comment: There's only 4 wednesdays in sep/16 anyways. so strtotime is doing the best it can with the "bad" information you gave it. just like asking for `feb 30/2016` will return a March timestamp. and strtotime and date will NEVER return null. they'll return a timestamp(int) or formatted date string, or a boolean false for failure.

Comment: @MarcB I suspect he would have been satisfied if it returned `false` for his use case, i.e. a date that doesn't exist in the month should cause failure.

Comment: then you'd have to double-check the parsing. e.g. `$temp = strtotime('Fifth Wednesday of September 2016'); if (date('M', $temp) != 'Sep')) { return null }`.

Comment: @MarcB This is an old question but it exists in the unanswered list despite being resolved (judging from the upvoted comments).  Please submit your comments as a consolidated answer so Verl can award it the green tick, and future SO readers can simply read an answer instead of wading through the comments.  Thank you.